# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status, gcc

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile the following program,I am given the following error

```
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ gcc fgetline.c -Wall -o enquote
/tmp/ccFnIr1N.o: In function `main':
fgetline.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `fgetline'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After a bit of reading, I have found this error is caused by either, a spelling mistake or a missing library. I am unsure which library might be missing.

Header file "fgetline.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int fgetline(FILE *fp,  char *line, int max);
FILE *fp,*fpc;
#define max 30
char line[max+1];
```

fgetline.c

```
#include "fgetline.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
            if (argc !=3)
            {
                    printf( "usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite \n"      );
                    exit(1);
            }



            fp = fopen (argv [1], "r");
            if ( !fp)
                    {
                            printf("Couldn't open copy file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                            return -1;
                    }

            fpc = fopen (argv [2], "r+");

             if ( !fpc)
                    {
                            printf("Couldn't open write file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                            return -1;
                    }


while(1)
{
  /* read string from first file*/
  int length = fgetline(fp, line, 30 );
  /* if fail to read, break from loop*/
  if (length == -1)
    {

      break;
    }
    printf("\"%s\"\n",line); /*add "" around all strings read to new file*/
}
    fclose (fp);
    fclose (fpc);
    return 0;
}
```

As I said, not a spelling error from what I can tell and from what else I have read it must be a missing lib, I compile using  gcc fgetline.c -Wall -o enquote
if that helps at all. If you see other errors please feel free to point them out, the program is two take two arguments from the command line, loop through the first file, and send each string to the second file with " added to the start and finish of the string.

Comment: 1) do not declare variable instances in a header file!  2) do not use tabs for indenting. Every wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set individually,  Suggest using 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and still allows lots of indent levels across the page.   3) indent consistently:  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: always place an 'include guard' around every header file

Comment: do not include header files when/where their contents are not used.

Comment: strongly suggest you read the man page for `perror()` and use it rather than messing with `strerror()` and `errno`

Comment: regarding this line: `printf( "usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite \n" );`  1) this fails to output the error message to stderr.  2) this makes a (probably wrong) assumption about what the executable file name is.  Strongly suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s srcFile, destFile \n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Couldn't open copy file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));`  1) this fails to output the error message to stderr, Strongly suggest: `perror( "fopen for input file failed" );`

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Couldn't open write file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));`  1) fails to output the error message to stderr, Strongly suggest: `perror( "fopen for output file failed" );`

Comment: Of critical importance, there is no 'standard' C library function named: `fgetline()`  Perhaps you meant `getline()`  Which does require proper parameters and is found in the standard c library and the prototype is referenced by: `#include <stdio.h>` and has a prototype of: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`  Strongly suggest reading the man page for the details

Comment: after correcting the code, the `while(1)` and call to `getline()` should be modified to: `char * line = NULL; ssize_t length; while( -1 != (length= getline( &line, NULL,  fp ); ) ) {...}`

Comment: the posted code is missing a line: `fprintf( fpc, "\"%s\"\n", line );`  so as to actually output the data to the new file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says you are calling the function `fgetline()` from `main()` but the definition of `fgetline()` couldn't be located. This is probably because you didn't link with the library that `fgetline()` is a part of or didn't compile the object file containing `fgetline()` when compiling main().

The header you include only contains a *declaration* but the *definition* of `getline()` is needed to produce the final executable. Perhaps, you meant to use POSIX getline?

If it's your own function then you need to compile with its definition.